# Navbar collapsed is closing while clicking on dropdown-toggle

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When the navbar is collapsed, I can't click on the elements on the dropdowns because when I click on a dropdown, it's closing the navbar. How can I avoid this behavior ?

```
<nav ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navCollapsed" ng-click="navCollapsed=true">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li id="home-tab" ng-class="{active : isActive('home-tab')}" ng-click="activateTab('home-tab')" class="tab"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
                <li id="stats-tab" ng-class="{active : isActive('stats-tab')}" ng-click="activateTab('stats-tab')" class="tab"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span>Stats</a></li>
                <li id="administration-tab" ng-class="{active : isActive('administration-tab')}" ng-click="activateTab('administration-tab')" class="tab dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>Administration<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terminal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="profile-tab" ng-class="{active : isActive('profile-tab')}" ng-click="activateTab('profile-tab')" class="tab dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Profile<span class="caret"></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="logout-tab" class="tab"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2sqd2k2t/4/)

**Note:** In the JSFiddle example, when you click on a dropdown, it is not expending. I don't know why, anyway it is working in my code. Forget that and look at the issue that makes my collapsed navbar closing while clickng on a dropdown. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have

```
ng-click="navCollapsed=true"
```

on the main navbar div

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navCollapsed" ng-click="navCollapsed=true">
```

which means that the navbar closes anywhere you click on it, not just on the tabs.

Here is a version that doesn't collapse the navbar when you click on 'Administration' - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v9p9gnf/1/)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="navCollapsed">
```

New activateTab:

```
$scope.activateTab = function(tabId) {
    if (tabId != 'administration-tab') {
        $scope.navCollapsed = true;
    }
    $scope.activeTab = tabId;
};
```